# Nginx config for php-fpm in a dir /forum for a PHP forum

Tags: centos, nginx, php-fpm

I have a working Nginx config for a static HTML site. I need to add a forum at http://blah.com/forum, php-fpm is installed and working as a unix socket (I have tested and got this working via a test sub domain). But I can't get /forum to work, could someone post a working php-fpm config that will work in a sub dir?

Currently my site resides at /usr/share/nginx/html/ and my forum will be /usr/share/nginx/html/forum

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your Nginx to fastcgi_pass the forum requests to your PHP backend. That's an example:

```
location /forum {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/forum;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.socket;
}
```